# Post processor MediatR

Tags: c#, mediatr

I'm trying to use the post processor in MediatR, but it doesn't work in either the Pre processor or the Post processor. That's how I injected the post and pre processor, but apparently not properly.

Comment: I have a feeling that something is missing in the post

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyPreProcessor<TRequest> : IRequestPreProcessor<TRequest>
{
    public Task Process(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        
        Console.WriteLine("Pre-processing logic executed");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class MyPostProcessor<TRequest, TResponse> : IRequestPostProcessor<TRequest, TResponse>
{
    public Task Process(TRequest request, TResponse response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        
        Console.WriteLine("Post-processing logic executed");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}   

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
            
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(MyPreProcessor<>));
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(MyPostProcessor<,>));

    
    services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
}
   
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
               
        app.UseMediatR();
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to return response model